# Java 8: removing duplicate after addall twice, possible concurrency issue?

Tags: java, concurrency

I know this is an old topic, but the following strange test case looks NEW, at least to myself, thanks in advance!

Problem:
I am expecting duplicate items will be removed, but the result is NOT stable, i.e, if run several times, then results are not same. There could be a concurrency issue behind this codes.

if add duplicate item right one after another, then the code is fine.
But, if using addall twice (just for testing purpose), then the expecting result is NOT stable.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TestJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<TestObj> result = new ArrayList<>();

        List<TestObj> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<TestObj> tempList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<TestObj> tempResult = new ArrayList<>();

        int size = 3;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            TestObj testObj = new TestObj();
            testObj.setField1("555");
            testObj.setField2("" + i);
            tempList.add(testObj);

            TestObj testObj2 = new TestObj();
            testObj2.setField1("555");
            testObj2.setField2("" + i);
            tempList2.add(testObj2);

            // tempResult.add(testObj); // <-- if use this, then no concurrency issue
            // tempResult.add(testObj2);
        }

        tempResult.addAll(tempList);
        tempResult.addAll(tempList2);

        System.out.println("expecting 6, actual = " + tempResult.size());

        FilterComparator comp = new FilterComparator();

        result = tempResult.stream() //
                .filter(new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>(comp)::add)//
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("expecting 3, actual = " + result.size()); // <-- Here, looks like there is a concurrency issue! 
    }

    public static class TestObj {
        private String field1;
        private String field2;
        private String field3;

        public String getField1() {
            return field1;
        }

        public void setField1(String field1) {
            this.field1 = field1;
        }

        public String getField2() {
            return field2;
        }

        public void setField2(String field2) {
            this.field2 = field2;
        }

        public String getField3() {
            return field3;
        }

        public void setField3(String field3) {
            this.field3 = field3;
        }

    }

    public static class FilterComparator implements Comparator<TestObj> {
        public int compare(TestObj o1, TestObj o2) {
            if (compareIfSameString(o1.getField1(), o2.getField1()) //
                    && compareIfSameString(o1.getField2(), o2.getField2()) //
            ) {
                return 0;
            }

            return 1;
        }
    }

    public static boolean compareIfSameString(String oldValue, String newValue) {
        if (isReallyEmptyOrNull(oldValue) && isReallyEmptyOrNull(newValue)) {
            return true;
        }

        return Objects.equals(oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public static boolean isReallyEmptyOrNull(String value) {
        return value == null || "".equals(value.trim());
    }

}
```

Update: for later on reference
thanks JB Nizet for your comment. I modified comparator as following and everything is fine!

```
public static class FilterComparator implements Comparator<TestObj> {
    public int compare(TestObj o1, TestObj o2) {
        if (o1.getField1() == null) {
            if (o2.getField1() != null) {
                return o2.getField1().compareTo(o1.getField1());
            }
        } else if (o1.getField1().compareTo(o2.getField1()) != 0) {
            return o1.getField1().compareTo(o2.getField1());
        }

        if (o1.getField2() == null) {
            if (o2.getField2() != null) {
                return o2.getField2().compareTo(o1.getField2());
            }
        } else if (o1.getField2().compareTo(o2.getField2()) != 0) {
            return o1.getField2().compareTo(o2.getField2());
        }

        if (o1.getField3() == null) {
            if (o2.getField3() != null) {
                return o2.getField3().compareTo(o1.getField3());
            }
        } else if (o1.getField3().compareTo(o2.getField3()) != 0) {
            return o1.getField3().compareTo(o2.getField3());
        }
        return 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your comparator violates the Comparator contract (It only returns 0 or 1, never any negative number). The lambda passed to filter always creates a new Set, which doesn't make much sense. Obey the rules, and everything should work by the rules. Also, there can't be any concurrency issue, since you're doing everything in a single thread.

Comment: Thanks! you are right, I should improve my comparator.

Comment: Your comparator does not impose a total ordering. See the documentation​ at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparator is wrongly implemented, check these inversion of values and you will get no only the same results every time but discover the second value expected is 2 not 3. ;-)

```
 public static class FilterComparator implements Comparator<TestObj> {

        public  int compare(TestObj o1, TestObj o2) {
            if (compareIfSameString(o1.getField1(), o2.getField1()) //
                    && compareIfSameString(o1.getField2(), o2.getField2()) //
            ) {
                return 1;// here
            }

            return 0; //and here
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes, this might be the reason, I will try ... thanks!

Comment: Thanks! That is the root reason, I will improve my comparator!